# How to calculate the diffierence between values of the same colum according to conditions

Tags: r, time-series, difference

I have a long df containing paired values. I need to calculate the difference between timepoints.

```
   ID    Sample_ID  Treatment Timepoint  Score
   Amu      A          Contr      0       10
   Amu      A          Contr      1       5
   Amu      A          Treat      0       11
   Amu      A          Treat      1       7
   Amu      B          Contr      0       9
   Amu      B          Contr      1       4
   Amu      B          Treat      0       10
   Amu      B          Treat      1       6
```

What I would like to do is to group by ID, sample_ID, treatment, and then caculate the difference of Score's values between Timepoint "1" and "0".
I should get :

```
 Amu_A_Contr = (5-10)
 Amu_A_Treat = (7-11)
 etc.
```

I tried with the following code:

```
group_by(ID,Sample_ID, Treatment)%>%
  mutate(Diff = lead(Score) - Score )
```

but the groupping function, for some reason fails, thus if someone can help it would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: does `group_by(ID,Sample_ID, Treatment)%>%  summarise(Diff = last(Score) - first(Score))` what you need?

Comment: Partially. For some reason, for some of the entries, it calculates the difference between wrong rows.  Sometimes, it groups like this:
`
   Amu      A          Contr      0       10
   Amu      A          Treat       0       11
   Amu      A          Contr      1       5
   Amu      A          Treat       1       7
`
But not always, thus I was wondering if is there another way.

Comment: perhaps you need yo `arrange` by timepoint first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd go about it is to pivot the timepoints to columns and then the diff is straightforward

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = rep('AMU', 8),
                 Sample_ID = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4)),
                 Treatment = c('Contr', 'Contr', 'Treat', 'Treat', 'Contr', 'Contr', 'Treat', 'Treat'),
                 Timepoint = rep(c(0, 1), 4),
                 Score = c(10, 5, 11, 7, 9, 4, 10, 6)
                 )

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Sample_ID, Treatment), 
              names_from = 'Timepoint', 
              values_from = 'Score', 
              names_glue = "time_{Timepoint}") %>% 
  mutate(diff = time_1 - time_0)
```